# How can I find Selenium XPath for the element placed in input tag?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find Selenium Xpath for element in the input tag. But, I'm not getting the value. I have used following code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver,
10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME("input"))))      
searchBox = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"))
```

But, it is not working!!!

Comment: can you give the URL or HTML?

Comment: [link](https://paytm.com/shop) is the url. In this url, I'm trying to get the exact **XPath** for search bar.

Comment: I can see there are many number of input tags. can try using elements/findElements

Comment: Not working? what kind of error is showing up? Please read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want for **search bar** in that link.

Comment: It is not showing any error. But, just not getting the value needed for that search bar.

Comment: Your question is referring to XPath but your code is not using XPath. Your question is not clear. Please add more detail so we can understand what you are asking and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more specific finder like `By.ID` this will look for an id on the web page since id is unique this should work better.

The id of the search box is `input_0` you can look it up via the inspect element from your browser, or via the development tools usually hidden under the F12 key

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID("input_0")))) 

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('input_0')
```

Have a read over here [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for more information about locators.

Let me know if it helped and if you learned something today :)

Comment: @DebanjanB Not yet. But, trying with other options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any issue with your line of code or locator. But you may consider trying the line of code below along with a few points:

- The `URL` `https://paytm.com/shop` takes a bit of time to load properly, so we need to wait for the HTML DOM to be completely loaded. Using `ExplicitWait` is the right choice.
- You can consider increasing the time limit from 10 to 20 seconds.
- Instead of `TAG_NAME` locator consider using `XPATH` locator.
- Your line of code will look like:

  ```
  search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='input_0']"))
  )
  search_box.click()
  ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.